# Where is the return object of java substring method created?

Tags: java

,the below code :

```
String str1 = "SachinTendulkar";
String str2 = str1.substring(6, str1.length());
String str3 = "Tendulkar";
```

the values in str2 and str3 are the same, but they do not refer to the same objects, what is exactly happening, where is str2 object created?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str2 = str1.substring(6, str1.length());
```

The above line will create a new Object, however `String str3 = "Tendulkar";` is String literal and may reuse an instance from the `string constant pool`. String literals are by default `intern` String object and creating a String object using `new String` is not `intern` by default.
Now if you create an object with `new String("Some String")` it will explicitly create a new `String` object in heap. Now let take a look at `String#substring` method it returns like below. That means it will create a new String Object every time it successfully executes.

```
return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == value.length)) ? this
                : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
```

Answer (score 0):

String is the only class that can be instanciated using characters, that means it's exactly as if you wrote 
    String str2 = new String(str1.substring(6, str1.length()));
So basically str2 is a new instance of the String class, so is str3, they are two different objects.